# Testing an AngularJS Controller method that returns a promise using Jasmine and Sinon

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, promise, sinon

I'm trying to test an Angular controller method that returns a promise. I stubbed out the promise-returning method (using a sinon stub), but when the promise is resolved (fulfilled), the registered success/onFulfilled handler does not get called. Basically, I can't get resolved promises in a Jasmine test to fire any of its registered handlers. See code here - http://cl.ly/code/1o1s2Y2F381c

Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: You need to manually run a digest.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, I had to use Jasmine's **runs** and **waitsFor** functions to basically tell jasmine to hold off moving on to the next test until I'm done with this test. Seems you need to do this if any part of your test runs in a future turn of the event loop (i.e. is async).

You could also use an extension like **jasmine.async** https://github.com/derickbailey/jasmine.async or **jasmine-as-promised** https://github.com/ThomasBurleson/jasmine-as-promised .